# How to post the values from Ajax page to main page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, popup

Working with check boxes I am loading a pop up and replace the HTML block with Ajax in that pop up. If any check box is checked or unchecked I need to update the query. For that I need a solution.

Comment: Can you show us a bit of your effort?

Comment: if you write code snippet here, that would be helpful to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="test1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="test2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="test3"/> ...
```

In your server side you will get an array with `status` which are all checked, then you can use this array for updation

Suppose `test1` and `test3` are checked

`status` `array` will be

```
array ('test1', 'test3');
```

Hope this is your need

Comment: This depends on what the asker is using server side (I assume this works in PHP).  This is definitely not true, for example, for Java servers.